# Encoding issue using ionic-framework

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, ionic-framework, ionic-view

In my App, I build a json and post it to the server

```
(....)
json = {"userID": idUser,  "name":$scope.data.name,
                          "type":AppService.getType().value, "race":$scope.data.race.name, "age":$scope.data.age}

(....)
$http.post(apiEndPoint+'/myapp/save', json)
```

I am having problems when race.name has special characters. Everything is UTF-8.
The value is sent by the server and I know it is OK because it is correctly shown on the UI.
When the Ionic App sends it back, it mess up with the encoding.

For example, when the user selects "testxxÃxx" at the interface, the server get something like this:

```
[userID:4, age:2342, name:Test, type:TEST, race:testxx??xx]
```

Just to be clear, "testxxÃxx" is correctly shown on the UI (on a selector).
At first I thought it could be a Ionic View limitation, but it is not. It happens using the iOS emulator as well.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you setted header of HTTP POST requests to UTF-8 ??

```
.config(["$httpProvider",
         function(httpProvider) {
              httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;
             httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
             return httpProvider['defaults']['transformRequest'] = function(
                     data) {
                 if (data == null) {
                     return data;
                 }
                 return $.param(data);
             };
         } ])
```

Comment: Good idea. I tried: 

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=utf-8';

But it does not work.
Same problem.